# Submit form using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently working on my webpage where I'm using an anchor tag to process the request. Here is the portion of my code:

```
<a href="?redirect=Pro" target="_blank">I AGREE</a>
```

It works okay. However, I added an input field and I have to include that in my process on `"?redirect=Pro"`. My input field value is not being processed because the form is not being submitted/processed. I already tried the:

```
<form id="discount">
      <input type="hidden" id="coupon_applied">
</form>
<a id = "agree" onclick="document.getElementById('discount').submit()" href="?redirect=Pro" target="_blank">I AGREE</a>
```

But I still can't get it to work.

I can't remove the `?redirect=Pro` because that's where all my process is happening. 
Any advice on how I i will modify my code to accommodate this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: This is a preview of my pricing.php file for more info:

```
<?php
     session_start();
     $link=$_GET['redirect'];
     $discount_amount = $_POST['coupon_applied'];
if ($link == 'Pro')
     {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$discount_amount')</script>";
    }
?>

<form id="discount" action="pricing.php" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" id="coupon_applied">
</form>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('discount').submit()" href="?redirect=Pro" target="_blank">I AGREE</a>
```

With my current code, echo is returning blank/null.

Comment: Do you want to redirect with the value of hidden 'coupon_applied'?

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting (if any) or how you are expecting it to redirect ?

Comment: What do you mean by "where my process is happening"? First of all, your form is missing a method and action, and second, I am not sure what the code is supposed to do so it's difficult to advise anything further.

Comment: @DsRaj yes, that's what i want to do! i added the 'form action = "pricing.php"' but i get null

Comment: From where you are going to add value in the hidden field because now there is nothing in hidden field

Answer (score 4):

You should use a `method` and `action` in your form like: `<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">`